# rails, how to combine two ActiveRecord query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following association

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location
end
```

Suppose I have some instances of Location, I what to query all items belong to those locations. Currently I managed to get the result as an array

```
items =[]
Location.near(latitude,longitude,distance).find_each do |location|
      location.items.find_each do |item|
           items << item
      end
end
```

However, is there any way I can get the results as ActiveRecord::Relation. Because I want to further query the results by using "where" with ActiveRecord::Relation.

P.S. The "near" method is from geocoder gem, it returns a ActiveRecord::Relation.

---------------------Edit----------------------------

Thank you for replies I nearly find the solution

```
locations = Location.near(latitude,longitude,distance)
Item.where(location_id: locations.pluck(:id))
```

Is it the right way to do it? to me it is a bit unintuitive.

----------------------Edit again ---------------------------

Just a small comment: I say it is unintuitive because I am switching from DataMapper. If it is Datamapper, it would be quite simple,  like

```
Location.near(blabla).items
```

It is very simply to make queries through associations. Compared to Datamapper, can not understand why ActiveRecord association is so useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit to use one query with mapping...

What billy said above, but another option that might be faster:

```
locations = Location.near(1, 2, 3)
items = Item.where(:location_id => locations.map(&:ids)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the tricky thing is , I am using a geocoder gem. I need to search location according to distance by using "near" and the near method stop me from building a single "where" query

Comment: I think you wanted `Items.where...`

Comment: @GingerJim, can you chain them together in activerecord format? I'll look at Geocoder's options to see. But I imagine you can.

Comment: cool, "map" looks quite unfamiliar to me, I will look into that, thank you

Comment: Guys, I will delete mine as that is a bit duplicate of combining of yours, thanks for vote though.

Comment: @BillyChan - A lot of variations on same principle. Someone showed me map a year ago and I've used that more often. Wonder which one is technically faster.

Comment: @GingerJim map is helpful, just an easy way to take any attribute from an array of values and grab one of them in an array for use. Pluck might accomplish the same goal these days?

Comment: I'm not sure if that ',' is supposed to be there?

Comment: @Jordan been a while since I answered this, but I think you're right. I removed it.